# Hide detail in Oracle report

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report, reportbuilder

I'm making a report in Oracle reports 10g, and all I want to show is totals. I want the detail lines removed so that the total line is all the displays for each date. I can hide the details, but the report still leaves the spaces and I can't figure out how to close the gap between the date and total lines so they display evenly next to each other.

Comment: consider writing a query that only returns the totals and building on it?

Answer (score 3):

Put the detail stuff inside of a frame and set the frame's vertical elasticity to "Variable". Then put a format trigger on that frame that returns false when you want to hide it. Everything below it should move up to fill the space then when the format trigger returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Put the conditional formatting on "Repeating Frame" and check on hide the object. 
Then all rows meeting condition will be hidden. And no space will left.